# Wigner flow for open quantum systems

Tags: quantum-mechanics, phase-space, open-quantum-systems, wigner-transform

In the paper by [Friedman and  Blencowe](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.04844.pdf) the Wigner flow for an open quantum system is derived.
On page 3 the Wigner flow for the harmonic oscillator is derived. Substituting the potential $V = \frac{1}{2} \omega_0^2 x^2$ into equation (4) leads them to Equation (11) which is only linear in $\omega_0$. I don't see how this happens, what am I missing?

Comment: That has the distinct look of a typo.

Comment: Probably, I was wondering because the same "typo" appears in equation (10) as well.

Comment: Yes, but $\partial_x V' = m \omega_0^2 x$, correct? I don't see how one of the $\omega_0$ cancels.

Comment: Oh... you worry not about the number of terms but about the dimensional consistency of the term... @Emilio is, of course right. They should have had a squared $\omega_0$, for the top component of the current to be dimensionally consistent with the lower one. That is, $[J_x /J_p]=[x/p]$ for the phase space divergence to make dimensional sense.

Comment: @CosmasZachos, can you maybe give me a reference how the Wigner current for the environment is added? I understood from your book the that the part of the system orginates from the Moyal Bracket, but I dont see how I can include the environment analogously.

Comment: oh... maybe [Bondar, Cabrera, etal 2016](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/acs.jpclett.6b00498).

Comment: and [also](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdfplus/10.1021/acs.jpclett.8b01793) ...